# Get username in Symfony (in Twig) on page, which is accessible to anonymous users

Tags: php, authentication, twig, symfony-2.6

Is there a way to access username of the logged user on page, which is accessible to anonym users in Symfony 2.6.1?

Example:
I have main page, where is link to login and if there is a user logged in, I want to display his username as a link to his account instead of the login link.

If I use `{{ app.user.username }}` it will display error

```
Impossible to access an attribute ("username") on a NULL variable ("")
```

because `app.user` is null object on pages with `security: false` defined is *security.yml*. It will work only on pages, which needs to be under firewall with no `security: false`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*You should try something like this:

set a default value for anonymous :*

```
{{ app.user.username|default('Not Logged') }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if i understood your problem correctly, but its true that `{{ app.user.username }}` throws an exception, because there is not user object if you are not logged in. So just check if the object exists:

```
{% if app.user is defined %}
    {# link to account #} 
{% else %}
    {# link to login #}
{% endif %}
```

If this hint is not the exspected one, give us some code.

Comment: But I want to get username even if "app.user" is not defined. Is it possible?

Comment: Then you have to get the user object by id. Something like `$this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('User')->find($id)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
{{ app.security.getToken().getUser() }}
```